# Why is the time complexity of DFS to detect a cycle in an undirected graph O(|V|) and not O(|V| + |E|)?

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

Can anyone explain to me in detail why and how the upper bound of DFS to detect a cycle in an undirected graph be O(|V|) ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A graph without cycles has at most |V| - 1 edges (it's a **forest**). Therefore, if the DFS discovers |V| edges or more, then it has already found a cycle and terminates. The runtime is accordingly bounded by O(|V|).

Comment: Upvoted :) A graph without cycles has at most |V|-1 edges. Maybe that's what you meant, because later you say "if the DFS discovers |V| edges or more..."

Comment: @PaulHankin: Thanks, I didn't pay attention for the constants (the question is about asymptotic). :)